# run Perl script as another user on windows

Tags: windows, services, perl

I want to run perl script  automatically  every day on win32 with different user than the currently-logged on user could someone provide an idea ?
?

Comment: This is a dupe of many questions on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the administrator password, Windows supports this:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;294676&sd=tech

There are also sudo-like programs for Windows ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/ ) which are somewhat more flexible that runas.

Comment: That deals with the "with different user" but completely misses the "automatically every day" bit.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you run the script from the windows' "schedule task"?
You can also set it to run with a different user.

Or use RJBS App::Cronjob which I read from his advent calendar here:
http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/2009-12-07.html

Not sure if that will work on windows though...